# MySQL database relationship without an ID

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, relation

Hi StackOverflow community,

I have these two tables:

**tbl_users**

- ID_user (*PRIMARY KEY*)
- **Username** (*UNIQUE*)
- Password
- ...

**tbl_posts**

- ID_post (*PRIMARY KEY*)
- **Owner** (*UNIQUE*)
- Description
- ...

Why always everybody make database relationships with foreign keys? What about if I want to relate **Username** with **Owner** instead of doing ID_user with ID_user in both tables?

Username is UNIQUE and the Owner is the username of the creator of the post.

Can it be done like that? There is something to correct or make better? Maybe I have a misconception.

I would appreciate detailed and understandable answers.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can be done... Buy you don't want to have the same username stored 1000's of times, if that user later changes name...

Comment: can be done but working with strings is much expensive than numbers, so with millions of records your joins will be slower than using IDs.

Comment: Got the point, thank you for the fast answer! Now I understand why it's too better relating with IDs.

Comment: And, in reality, you are using the field as a foreign key.

Comment: @Mahmoud Working with strings might slightly more expensive, but that's not the reason.

Comment: @Strawberry, I didn't understand your mean but as you know the most important operation in joins is comparison between primary key of two tables. Now in the other hand we know comparing strings needs char by char comparison in which each of them is an integer comparison that result several times more cpu cycles. Finally when we need millions of comparisons the needed time will increase dramatically.

Comment: @Mahmoud Pls see example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is primarily for data integrity. The argument concerning performance is a little misleading. While neither exhaustive, nor definitive, I hope this little example will shed some light on that fact:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(i INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,s CHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

STEP1:

INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table (s) 
SELECT CONCAT(CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97)
             ,CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97)
             );

STEP2:

INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table (s) 
SELECT CONCAT(CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97)
             ,CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97),CHAR((RAND()*26)+97)
             )
  FROM my_table;

[REPEAT STEP 2 SEVERAL TIMES]

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table;
  +----------+
  | COUNT(*) |
  +----------+
  |    16384 |
  +----------+
  1 row in set (0.01 sec)

 SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY i LIMIT 12;;
  +----+------------+
  | i  | s          |
  +----+------------+
  |  1 | kkxeehxsvy |
  |  2 | iuyhrk{vaq |
  |  3 | ngpedelooc |
  |  4 | irkbyqgkhc |
  |  6 | yqkcifcxdz |
  |  7 | sgezlgvjjq |
  |  8 | blavbvxbnl |
  |  9 | wdbtqvgvgt |
  | 13 | pakzpbnhxr |
  | 14 | vpoy{gdwyd |
  | 15 | ezlhz{drwg |
  | 16 | ncwcwbpudh |
  +----+------------+

  SELECT * FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.i < x.i ORDER BY x.i,y.i LIMIT 1;
  +---+------------+---+------------+
  | i | s          | i | s          |
  +---+------------+---+------------+
  | 2 | iuyhrk{vaq | 1 | kkxeehxsvy |
  +---+------------+---+------------+
  1 row in set (1 min 22.60 sec)

 SELECT * FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.s < x.s ORDER BY x.s,y.s LIMIT 1;
  +-------+------------+------+------------+
  | i     | s          | i    | s          |
  +-------+------------+------+------------+
  | 21452 | aabetdlvum | 6072 | aabdnegtav |
  +-------+------------+------+------------+
  1 row in set (1 min 13.59 sec)
```

So, we have two queries doing essentially the same thing (a comparison of 270 million values). The first joins the table to itself on an integer value. The second joins the table to itself on a string value. Both columns are indexed. As you can see, in this example, the string join actually performs better than the integer join - even though the hit on the CPU may actually be greater!